# How to fix bootloop

Tags: adb, fastboot

I unlocked the bootloader using fastboot, this command; `fastboot flashing unlock` I had downloaded the phone's firmware (Infinix note 7) and patched the boot.img using magisk I then flashed the boot with the magisk_patched_boot.img using fastboot;

```
fastboot flash boot magisk_patched.img
```

After flashing it, the phone has not been booting, it displays the message below:

```
Orange state- this device can't be trusted as it is unlocked. Reboot in 5 sec and reboot
```

then it goes off, and on again.... this has been repeating itself over and over

I was requesting if there is a way, I can bring back the phone and root it with no issues state- this device can't be trusted as it is unlocked. Reboot in 5 sec and reboot

then it goes off, and on again.... this has been repeating itself over and over

Any idea on how to fix please?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix a bootloop is to remove the cause of the bootloop. Yes some phones reject the magisk patched image because recenctly i wanted to change a phone from system to systemless root. Phones which i think have no problem with magisk are Samsung phones.

Sincd you said you had downloaded a firmware, flash the original boot img that you patched with magisk and then your phone will be back to normal. LG phones also reject patched boot images. If your phone refuses the boot image you must then try rooting using using pc client rooting apps or even android client rooting apps.